# Replace part of link URL string - why not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to take a link such as:

```
<a class="popup" href="http://www.example.com/puppies">More info</a>
```

and turn it into this:

```
<a class="popup" href=".puppies">More info</a>
```

I am using this code, which effectively adds the period, but it doesn't remove the URL:

```
$('a.popup').each(function(){
    var lnk = this.href;
    this.href = lnk.replace('http://www.example.com/', '.');

});
```

Do you know why it isn't working and how I can fix it? The code above is giving me this:

```
<a class="popup" href="http://www.example.com/.puppies">More info</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Nope, works perfectly for me.

Comment: Oh weird... It's adding the period for me, but leaving the rest of the URL. The links are dynamically generated, but I would assume that if it was an issue with the JS running before the link was loaded, then the period wouldn't be added either. Right?

Comment: You're right.  The code has to be executed after the `a` tags are created.

Comment: Are you looking at the raw source code? probably you are using a code inspector and it shows the fully qualified link, but in the raw code you have what you expect...

Comment: I am looking at the raw source code, and it's showing the full link (with the period in the right spot). When I tried it in a fiddle, it was correct. But on my live site, it's not removing the URL part. There must be some sort of conflict.

Comment: What is the specific reason for the dot?

Comment: It's for a popup, and I'm using a dot instead of a hash.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said about the source code. When I look at the raw source, it hasn't added the dot either. But if I CLICK the link, it has indeed added the dot (but again, still not removing the beginning of the URL). So perhaps that does suggest an issue with the JS running before the link is created?

Comment: href urls are treated a certain way. the browser will automatically prepend the current path to the URL if the first character isn't a `/` or a protocol string (`http://`, `https://`, etc). Does the dot need to be there for functionality or is it simply cosmetic?

Comment: It needs to be there for functionality. Essentially like an anchor link. However, I was able to get it working. I wrongly had it (document).ready, when I needed to put it in (window).load. Or, at least moving it to that, made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this .

Once link is available in DOM then you can do your logic

```
 function sample(){
    if($('a.popup').is(':visible') == true ){ 
    $('a.popup').each(function(){
        var lnk = this.href;
        this.href = lnk.replace('http://www.example.com/', '.');

    });
    }
    else{
    setTimeout( sample , 10 )

    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a try, but it's throwing an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" in the isvisible line. I don't see an error off hand....

Comment: Thank you. That still didn't seem to work (though there were indeed no errors with your revised code). However, you helped point me in the right direction. I just realized that my original code worked if I moved it to (window).load at the end of my JS docuemnt, as opposed to in (document).ready. I wasn't thinking clearly. Thank you!